# Call an external URL and post data to it (same as an HTML form does) from a controller

Tags: controllers, magento2.2, post-data

Is it possible to use `$this->_redirect()` in a controller to call an external url and post data to it the same way an HTML form does in Magento 2.2?

If yes, how?

If no, any suggested alternatives on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can redirect to external url using `->setRedirect('https://google.com'); exit;`.

Another way you could do is using `_redirectUrl($url);`.

I do not know abou posting data with `POST` request, but you can do it easily with `GET` request.

In the alterntive I'd suggest to use `cURL` to post whichever way you want.